# Is there any scenario when calling InvalidateMeasure, it does not trigger MeasureOverride method?

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control implemented.
When i call InvalidateMeasure for an UIElement; its MeasureOverride is not triggered.
Also, during this state, when width or height is changed MeasureOverride is not triggered.
MeasureOverride is triggered in almost in all the cases. But, there is specific scenario it is not getting triggered.

It is not possible for me to replicate the same issue in a simple demo, also i cannot share the custom control too.

Current workaround, is to invalidate one of UIElement's Nested Parent element (only once), and the measure override is triggered there after. But later when using the application the same issue occur again.

**So, is this a bug in WPF framework?

is there any scenario that stops the WPF framework calling MesureOverride, when InvalidateMeasure is called?**

*Some observations:*
In the following visual structure
As is stated earlier, if i invalidate 'Node' it is not working.
workaround: If i invalidate CustomScrollViewer (only once), it is working.
Clue: if i remove Annotations i cant see this problem ever.

Visual structure will be like this:

```
Control (a custom control)
-Grid
--CustomScrollViewer (a custom control)
---Border
----Grid
-----ContentPresenter
------Canvas
-------DiagramPage (a custom panel contains about 200 elements)
--------Node (a custom control)
---------Grid
----------AnnotationPanel (a custom panel contains about 2-3 elements)
-----------Annotation
```

Comment: "Is this a bug in WPF framework?" Certainly not. Besides that, it's impossible to answer your question without a [complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Did you try `UpdateLayout` instead of `InvalidateMeasure`?

Comment: @Clemens i tried UpdateLayout it is not calling Measure/Arrange override method.